# If I restore a database and overwrite the original is there any way to go back? SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, backup

I do not have a backup available but I wrote over an existing database with a backup file.

The problem is the one I wrote OVER had a Stored Proc that I need to get back. Any way to do this without a backup file of the database with the Stored Proc in it?

Comment: sorry mate, you're data is gone

Comment: Just had to re-write the stored proc in the end. The data was more up to the date, but I forgot to copy the script that created the stored proc. School boy error :-( but all sorted now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the answer is no.

It might be worth looking in your `%temp%` directory though at the files entitled `~`...`.sql` just in case you are extraordinarily lucky.

I have [SSMS toolspack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) installed and that keeps a log of all SQL statements executed in Management Studio which might have been useful in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you have a copy of the script that created the proc in the first place.